# pass vars from iframe to wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

i have an iframe in one domain

```
<iframe src="www.dsfsdfdsf.com/s_usr.php?currentuserurl=http://www.sddsd.com&currentuser=test" />
```

the s_usr.php on other domain (wordpres site):

```
if (isset($_GET["currentuser"])) { $currentuser = $_GET['currentuser']; }
if (isset($_GET["currentuserurl"])) { $currentuserurl= $_GET['currentuserurl']; }
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){ $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; }
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){ $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; }
```

the source site give the iframe with error 403

its seems that cant send vars thro iframe if ijust add the page with no vars the iframe is ok

```
<iframe src="www.dsfsdfdsf.com/s_usr.php/>
```

so how can i send them? maybe wordpress deny this?

the short answer **hostgator** :
"Looking into your issue it appears you are being stopped by our **mod security**"

Comment: try and encode the values maybe

Comment: Look in your server logs. See if they tell  you why it is returning a 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

If the source of the iframe is on an other domain, include the domain in the src attribute:

```
<iframe src="http://yourdomain.ex/s_usr.php?currentuserurl=http://www.sddsd.com&currentuser=test" />
```

Also check the x-frame-options header of the page included in the iframe. If the value is DENY, SAMEORIGIN you can not include the page as an iframe. If this is the case you should set the option to:
ALLOW-FROM: yourdomainhere

Comment: X-Frames-Options wouldn't generate a 403 HTTP error.